# Invalid Date/Time TimeStamp For Query On Dataset using Query Builder

Tags: vb.net, date

I'm using Query Builder in Visual Studio and coding in VB.NET

When creating a query in Query Builder my date gets reformatted to a date that my driver cannot process (Relativity ODBC Driver).

```
SELECT * 
FROM Consignments 
WHERE Consignments.DATE_ACTUAL >= '2017-03-27' 
  AND Consignments.DATE_ACTUAL <= '2017-03-27'
```

If I then preview the query the query will be reformatted to and run as:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Consignments 
WHERE Consignments.DATE_ACTUAL >= '27/03/2017' 
  AND Consignments.DATE_ACTUAL <= '27/03/2017'
```

Then I get a invalid date/time reply from the driver.

If I manually enter the date in the CommandText on designer view this works so I know the query is correct.

Though if I want to parse parameters as the date through the queries e.g `@FROMDATE - @TODATE` I get the same error. So how do I change the default date format for the Dataset?
I checked parameter properties and have tried selecting date.

Thanks

Comment: `DateTime` does not have a format, `'2017-03-27'` is text that just looks like a date to you

Comment: If this is the case do you know why Query Builder automatically reorders the date?

Comment: Because it is a UI tool designed and intended to translate things like a DateTime (636392706970000000L) into something a human (you) can understand.

Comment: I ended up leaving dataset designer and query builder as it was not only displaying the date in a different order but also sending the query in that way too. I programatically created an odbccommand connection etc.